# Oracle Cloud Logging's log ingestion using OCI .Net SDK. Error: "Unable to process JSON input"

Tags: c#, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, .net-5

I'm trying to put some logs into a custom (application) log using the OCI's log ingestion API but I keep receiving this quite vague error message: "Unable to process JSON input".
Despite the lack of documentation for the .Net SDK ([outside of class descriptions](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/dotnet/7.0.0/api/)), I managed to create a [PutLogs](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/logging-dataplane/20200831/LogEntry/PutLogs) request in .net 5. Confronting the generated HTTP request with the OCI's API documentation ([which is good](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/logging-dataplane/20200831/)) I don't see anything wrong with it, but the server keeps returning the error.

Here's a simple code that reproduces the problem:

```cs
using Oci.Common;
using Oci.Common.Auth;
using Oci.Common.Model;
using Oci.LoggingingestionService;
using Oci.LoggingingestionService.Models;
using Oci.LoggingingestionService.Requests;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security;

namespace LogIngestionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new LoggingClient(new SimpleAuthenticationDetailsProvider
            {
                TenantId = "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..(...)",
                UserId = "ocid1.user.oc1..(...)",
                Fingerprint = "3a:82:(...)",
                Region = Region.FromRegionId("sa-saopaulo-1"),
                PrivateKeySupplier = new FilePrivateKeySupplier(@".\oracle\dev.private.pem", new SecureString())
            });

            var putLogsRequest = new PutLogsRequest
            {
                LogId = "ocid1.log.oc1.sa-saopaulo-1.(...)",
                PutLogsDetails = new PutLogsDetails
                {
                    Specversion = "1.0",
                    LogEntryBatches = new List<LogEntryBatch>
                    {
                        new LogEntryBatch
                        {
                            Source = "ProductionIdentityServer",
                            Defaultlogentrytime = DateTime.Now,
                            Type = "AccessLogs",
                            Entries = new List<LogEntry>
                            {
                                new LogEntry
                                {
                                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                    Data = @"{ ""Message"": ""User not found."" }"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            try
            {
                var response = await client.PutLogs(putLogsRequest);
                Console.WriteLine($"Success! ({response.OpcRequestId})");
            }
            catch (OciException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Error: {ex.Message}\n" +
                    $"Service Code: {ex.ServiceCode}\n" +
                    $"opc-request-id: {ex.OpcRequestId}"
                );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}\n");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the generated HTTP request body:

```json
{
  "specversion": "1.0",
  "logEntryBatches": [
    {
      "entries": [
        {
          "data": "{ \"Message\": \"User not found.\" }",
          "id": "4da4f080-35bb-44e3-9713-df87dfd07878"
        }
      ],
      "source": "ProductionIdentityServer",
      "type": "AccessLogs",
      "defaultlogentrytime": "2020-12-01T10:08:30.5669775-03:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the server's response:

```json
{
  "code": "InvalidParameter",
  "message": "Unable to process JSON input"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the dotnet sdk 8.0.0 release. Can you please update the version being used in your csproj to 8.0.0 and try again?

Comment: Yeah, I updated when you guys replied to my ticket (I assume you work with OCI). Came here to tell others there was nothing wrong with the code. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: It was a bit of a guesswork to come up with this code from the classes documentation alone, please include some code samples using the new logging service in the github repository so others have a better understanding.

Comment: @HenriqueMiranda as per your recommendation we have added the example for the logging service: https://github.com/oracle/oci-dotnet-sdk/blob/master/Examples/LoggingExample.cs